# Can I use Ryanair Online Check-in with a permanent resident card?

Tags: schengen, ryanair, russian-citizens

I'm travelling to Italy from Greece for Christmas. I have a valid Russian Passport and a Permanent residence for EU family member card (which allows me to travel to Schengen countries).

Since Ryanair support wasn't very helpful, I want to know if I need to check-in at the airport to show my card, since online check-in only has an option for my passport.

Comment: I dont think that is a problem. Just check in as they request. Than take your residence card to the airport, just in case youre requested additional proof youcan be in schengen.

Comment: Is the question about checking in online or showing your travel documents when you get to the airport?  You'll probably have to do both: https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview#11-0

Answer (score -1):

## Answer

I agree with @nsn's comment - also, Ryanair's approach now is to encourage all passengers to use online check-in.

From [Ryanair's check-in policy](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/terms-and-conditions/termsandconditionsar_1379164564) today:

> **6.2** All passengers are required to check-in online via  https://www.ryanair.com/ and print or download a boarding pass except Business Plus fares which include free airport check-in.

---

## Context

For context, see [this Telegraph article from 2009](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/4972915/Ryanairs-online-check-in-policy-QandA.html) describing the change to their current online-only policy:

> **Do I have to check-in online?**
>
> From May 1, all new bookings will be required to use online check in, while Ryanair will begin phasing out check-in desks during the summer.
> Passengers who book tickets before May 1 will still be able to check in at the airport, but from March 19 the fee for airport check in will be doubled to £20 per person per flight, in an effort to persuade passengers to embrace the new system.

Also, the same article (remember, written in 2009) notes the policy change impacted non-EU citizens:

> **I’m not an EU citizen – can I fly with Ryanair?**
>
> Ryanair currently does not allow non-EU citizens and customers with reduced mobility to check-in online. From March 19, the service will be extended to these passengers.